# Push Notifications not showing when App is in Foreground

Tags: ios, swift

I am sending push notifications through my Node.js server and it works fine when the app is in background or closed but if the app is running and is in foreground, then the notifications do not show (although I am able to get the body & message printed in console even in foreground). Here is my app delegate file :

```
@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    var window : UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
        UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
                      // do only pure app launch stuff, not interface stuff
                  } else {

                      self.window = UIWindow()
                      let token = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "token")
                    
                      if token != nil {
                          guard let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navControllerHome") as? UIViewController else {
                              fatalError("Could not instantiate HomeVC!")
                          }
                          window?.rootViewController = vc
                      } else {
                          guard let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "startingNavCon") as? UIViewController else {
                              fatalError("Could not instantiate HomeVC!")
                          }
                          window?.rootViewController = vc
                      }

                      window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

                  }
        DropDown.startListeningToKeyboard()
        registerPushNotifications(application: application)
        return true
    }
     }

    func registerPushNotifications(application : UIApplication){
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in

            guard granted else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("Successfully registered")
        let tokenParts = deviceToken.map{ data in String(format : "%02.2hhx", data)}
        let token = tokenParts.joined()
        let saveSuccessful: Bool = KeychainWrapper.standard.set((token), forKey: "devicetoken")
        print(token)

    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Failed to register for Remote Notifications")
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        print("Did receive notification")
        print("USERINFO",userInfo)
        if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String : AnyObject],
           let alertDict = aps["alert"] as? String {
            print("Body :", alertDict)
        }
        completionHandler(.newData)
        }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("USER NotificationCenter Did Receive")
        completionHandler()
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        print("userNotificationCenter willPresent")
        completionHandler([.banner, .badge, .sound])
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong, please help.

Answer (score 1):

Missed this :

```
func registerForPushNotifications(application: UIApplication) {
    
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .alert, .sound], completionHandler: { (granted, error) in
        if granted {
            // Register after we get the permissions.
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        }
    })
}
```

Solved now.